# Arch-Linux: Chrome first start takes about 15 seconds

Tags: arch-linux, chrome

First start of Google-Chrome after boot takes about 10-15 Seconds, after that chrome starts immediately.

On my previous Fedora installation, this was not the case.

So I thought this must be something with my arch-linux installation/configuration. But I really don't have a clue how to track this problem down...

when I start chrome via terminal I get these error-messages:

> [1212:1212:0122/194748:ERROR:profile_sync_service.cc(1200)] History
>   Delete Directives datatype error was encountered: Delete directives
>   not supported with encryption.
>   [1212:1212:0122/194751:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: ntp
>   is not defined", source:  (1)

any suggestions?

Comment: Call chrome from a terminal and give us the output log of the program invocation so we can have more clues.

Comment: updated my question

Comment: Seems to be a kown bug:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=314188
Which version of chrome are you using?

Comment: Version 32.0.1700.77

Comment: the report I provided you is from version  32.0.1685.0  so this might still be an open issue.

Comment: mhmmm, maybe thanks for the link I will update my Question if there are any news...